# Postman gives response but ReactJS code throws error

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the records from an API but it returns unsuccessful response when I am using the below code. But at the same time, it is giving me proper response with status code 200 in postman. Here is my code. Please help:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
    
    const urlEndPoint = myEndPoint => "https://api.github.com/users/adhishlal"
    
    export default class Categories extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          requestFailed: false
       }
     }
    
    componentDidMount() {
    
    
       fetch(urlEndPoint(this.props.myEndPoint))
    
    
         .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) {
             throw Error(response.statusText)
           }
           return response
         })
    
         .then(d => response.json())
    
    
         .then(response => {
           this.setState({
             responseData: d
           })
         }, () =>
         {
           this.setState({
             requestFailed: true
           })
         })
    
    
     }
    
    render() {
    
    //If request is failed
    if(this.state.requestFailed)
    {
      return <div>Request Failed</div>
    }
    
    //Waiting for data to load from Zoho
    if(!this.state.responseData)
    {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    
    //Finally populate the data when loaded
    
    
    var indents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
     indents.push(
    
      <div className="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><div className="cr-openings">
      <p className="no-margin font-color-lightGrey no-of-openings">{i+1}</p><p className="catg-openings font-color-white">{this.state.responseData.name}</p>
      <p className="font-color-lightGrey city-openings no-margin">Bangalore , Chennai , Delhi NCR , Hyderabad , Mumbai</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    
      );
    }
    
    
    return (
      <section className="dotted">
          <div className="dotted-bg-dark">
            <div className="container padding-80-0">
              <div className="row m-b-30">
                {indents}
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
    );
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
    }
```

Can you suggest where I am making the mistake? You can run the API in your restclient or Postman to see the response.

Comment: Sounds like a CORS problem. Does your endpoint url has CORS enabled?

Comment: @Souradeep Nanda Checked with CORS too. It is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't completed your code but will show you how to get the data using fetch.

```
     fetch('https://api.github.com/users/adhishlal')
     .then(response => {
       response.json().then(function(data){
         console.log(data);
       })
```

the `data` in the code will be the data you require.

> The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

In my opinion using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead will make life a lot easier.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The code written above has few errors. Incorrect values have been returned at some places. Similarly, setState is done for wrong variable. Fixing those will make it run fine.

I have updated the piece of code which is causing the problem

```
.then(d => d.json())  //Return d.json() and not response.json()
   .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        responseData: response, //setState to response and not d
      })
   }, () =>
```